# calling SmartObjects method in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, k2, k2-blackpearl

I created a **SmartObject** in **K2 designer** and I added the WCF url as service reference.

Below is the code

```
UserDetailsSvcClient userDetail = new UserDetailsSvcClient();
userDetail.Open();
UserDetails userDC = new UserDetails();
var userDetailsList = userDetail.UserDetailsSvc_Load(userDC);
userDetail.Close();
```

But the `userDetailsList` always remains as `null`.

Also the `GetList` Smart method is not appearing

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you have enabled endpoints on the K2 Server. If not ,refer to the following, [Link to Endpoint Creation](http://help.k2.com/onlinehelp/k2blackpearl/userguide/4.6.4/webframe.html#walkthrough_create_managed_endpoint.html)
PS: You need to restart K2 Server before the changes are taken in to effect.

From the codes, seems like you are try to do a Load method. Load method will require a ID.

So for UserDetails userDC = new UserDetails();, add in the following:

```
userDC.Id = 1;
```

As for GetList, you dont need to pass it the UserDetails object.

```
var userDetailsList = userDetail.UserDetailsSvc_GetList(Null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I did not authorize the client.
I needed to add

```
userDetail.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

SO finally the code looked like this

```
UserDetailsSvcClient userDetail = new UserDetailsSvcClient();
    userDetail.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

userDetail.Open();
UserDetails userDC = new UserDetails();
var userDetailsList = userDetail.UserDetailsSvc_Load(userDC);
userDetail.Close();
```